# Storing the cookies in Express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I deploy the frontend and backend on a different server and I made in a function of login that the token will be stored in the cookie so when I login with frontend the token does not be stored but when I test login with postman the token is stored in postman correctly

```
const createToken = (id) => {
  return jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
  });
};

const createSendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
  const token = createToken(user._id);
  const cookieOptions = {
    expires: new Date(
      Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ),
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    domain: 'https://blog-full-websit.vercel.app',
  };

  res.cookie("jwt", token, cookieOptions);

  user.password = undefined;
  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: "success",
    token,
    data: {
      user,
    },
  });
};
exports.logIn = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  if (!email || !password) {
    return next(new AppError("please provide email and password", 400));
  }

  const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select("+password");

  if (!user || !(await user.checkPassword(password, user.password))) {
    return next(new AppError("invalid email or password", 401));
  }
  createSendToken(user, 200, res);
});
```

so when I post to the route login in postman the token is stored successfully but when I login with frontend the login process is successfully done but without storing the token to the cookies